# What is registration ID in Android and how does it creates internally?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Android and I don't understand some concepts.What is registration ID used in Google Cloud Messaging?How does it creates internally - it is unique device id as Apple device token or something else?How does it differs from application id? It is may be a stupid question but I really don't understand the concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the temporally ID that allows to GCM services identify your device-application, so trough your server you can send messages to GCM and this will redirect it to your device. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html)

In advance i copy some text:

> An ID issued by the GCM servers to the Android application that allows it to receive messages. Once the Android application has the registration ID, it sends it to the 3rd-party application server, which uses it to identify each device that has registered to receive messages for a given Android application. In other words, a registration ID is tied to a particular Android application running on a particular device.

Comment: Thanks but what id do I get when I do this:   
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

Comment: If you are registered to GCM services the RegistrationId, if it's an emtpy string it means that you have to register with `GCMRegistrar.register(context)`.

Answer (score 0):

It's documented quite fine there: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

For sender ID:

> Open the Google APIs Console page. If you haven't created an API
>   project yet, this page will prompt you to do so:
>
> Note: If you already have existing projects, the first page you see
>   will be the Dashboard page. From there you can create a new project by
>   opening the project drop-down menu (upper left corner) and choosing
>   Other projects > Create. Click Create project. Your browser URL will
>   change to something like:
>
> https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:4815162342
>
> **Take note of the value after #project: (4815162342 in this example). This is your project number, and it will be used later on as the GCM
>   sender ID.**

As for ID returned after GCM registration - how it is created is not really important, but it's unique ID per your device + the Google account active on the device.